# wso2 bpel: receive binary data with http binding

Tags: binding, wso2, bpel, cmis

I am trying to retrieve a file from CMIS in WSO2 BPS (bpel). I succeed in calling Alfresco, but /cmisatom/{repos}/content/file?{fileId} directly returns binary data. Is there a way to map this in the WSDL?

I now get the error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

Comment: A URL of `/cmisatom/` looks rather like the AtomPub binding - if you want to play with WSDLs doesn't that normally need the WebServices binding?

Comment: I tried that, but it seems not to be possible to enable Mtom on a partnerlink when using soap - which is a requirement for cmis. So that is the reason why I tried this.